# How to extract contained words by TokensRegex

Tags: stanford-nlp

for example, all the words contained "b"

In a sentence: "A boy is going to take a bus"

the result should be "boy" "bus"

Here is my rules but it does not work in this case.

```
{ 
 ruleType: "tokens",
 pattern: ( [ { word:/b/ } ]),
 result: Format("%s", "")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you need the regex to include wildcards before and after the "b": `/.*b.*/`:

```
{ 
 ruleType: "tokens",
 pattern: ( [ { word:/.*b.*/ } ]),
 result: Format("%s", "")
}
```

Comment: Awesome dude. Thanks so much